# Is there a standard replacement for three stacked LR1154 cells?

Tags: batteries

Some years ago I have seen a battery which alone could be used to replace three stacked LR1154 ("LR44") cells but I can't remember the name now. C... something I believe. I found this picture, if it helps, it's literally three LR44 shrinkwrapped:

[image]

Comment: With what voltage? CR14250  should be about that size. Have a look at the Wikipedia page that lists almost all battery sizes

Comment: 4.5V. I posted a picture.